# Mongoose Bulk upsert not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi i am new to nodejs and mongoose. Just trying to update mongo data with bulk inserts with following methods.

```
"use strict";
var mongo = require('../models/tracking_mongo');
var Schema = mongo.trackingMasterMongoosePoc.Schema;
//create a schema
var userwise_tracking_events = new Schema({
    activities      : {},
    summary         : {},
    userId          : Number,
    counter         : Number,
    created         : Date,
    modified        : Date
});

let collection = 'userwise_tracking_events';

let UserwiseTrackingEvents = mongo.trackingMasterConnPoc.model(collection, userwise_tracking_events);

UserwiseTrackingEvents.updateCollectionStream = function(condition, params, options, callback){
    var Bulk = UserwiseTrackingEvents.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    Bulk.find(condition).upsert().update(params);
    Bulk.execute(callback);
};

module.exports = UserwiseTrackingEvents;
```

Upper code works fine but this didn't solved my problem for using bulk inserts.

Then i just made a change by making the bulk variable global.

```
"use strict";
var mongo = require('../models/tracking_mongo');
var Schema = mongo.trackingMasterMongoosePoc.Schema;
//create a schema
var userwise_tracking_events = new Schema({
    activities      : {},
    summary         : {},
    userId          : Number,
    counter         : Number,
    created         : Date,
    modified        : Date
});

let collection = 'userwise_tracking_events';

let UserwiseTrackingEvents = mongo.trackingMasterConnPoc.model(collection, userwise_tracking_events);
var Bulk = UserwiseTrackingEvents.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
UserwiseTrackingEvents.updateCollectionStream = function(condition, params, options, callback){
    Bulk.find(condition).upsert().update(params);
    Bulk.execute(callback);
};

module.exports = UserwiseTrackingEvents;
```

Now getting the error find of undefined is not a function.

When i checked

console.log(UserwiseTrackingEvents.collection);

Gave me result with NativeCollection.collection is null.

Do let me know what i am doing wrong.

I have another methods to work on this but i specifically want what i am doing wrong in this question.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to say that your declaration of Bulk is not outside of any function declaration when moved out of the function call.  Thus when the exposed function is called , Bulk was not initialized.

Comment: Bulk was getting initialized but mongoose is not able to create connection when Bulk gets initialized.